# Find similar patterns in paintings? OpenCV

Tags: image, design-patterns, opencv, pattern-matching, shapes

I have an image of a mural painting which contains repetitions of some similar looking flowers. There is another image(smaller) of one of those flowers. I want to mark all the flowers similar to the flower in smaller image. How can I implement this in openCV? The similar looking flowers are not exactly the same. There are some distortions due to painter's inaccuracy.

NOTE: I have tried template matching, SIFT/SURF feature detector.

The image is like this
image link: link below

The smaller image to be queried is 
image link: link below

The results that I want and the results that I get by template matching are shown in the following image. In the following image all the encircled flowers are similar and should be searched but template matching only gives me only the ones that are marked with red star. Even after many iterations template matching does not give me other flowers.
image link: link below

All images are in this folder : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx3-s7he2z7xZ2tHVzhGb1A4a3c&usp=sharing

Comment: Can you lower the thresholds of template matching to get more matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the culprit is you're looking for a single resolution of template, which is much smaller than the flowers you want to find.

So, if you're using matchTemplate - you should run it several times. For different sizes of the template (make your flower bigger with resize). Another option is to scale the image down, and use the template of the same size.

Those approaches are rather simple, however, may be sub-optimal - you'll be doing a lot of work resizing and matching all over again. So, you should probably use feature matching and figure out what exactly goes wrong. Don't know if you've seen it, but you can follow the feature matching tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

**UPD**

I believe, I misinterpreted your image. I agree with you on the size now - it isn't such a big deal. Well, I don't know how you've done the matching, but the following code

```
Mat image = imread("/home/sergei/Documents/source.jpg");
Mat templ = imread("/home/sergei/Documents/template.jpg");
Mat dst;
matchTemplate(image, templ, dst, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
threshold(dst, dst, 0.2, 0.0, THRESH_TOZERO);

for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++)
    {
        if (dst.ptr<float>(i)[j] > 0.0)
        {
            imshow("candidate", image(Rect(j, i, templ.cols, templ.rows)));
            waitKey(0);
        }
    }
}
```

misses, I believe, 2 of the matches you consider valid. It gives you few false positives as well, but that's a start.

You can improve further by playing with threshold value and matching metric.

Comment: The template is cut/cropped from the same image. So I don't think resolution is the problem. Though the flowers not getting matched are a little big (but only a little - does that make much of a difference)- I suppose that the problem is the no. of petals in other flowers are a few more and the colour is also a bit distorted.

P.S. I have tried the link that you posted. It only finds the exact match not other similar ones.

Comment: your way of writing for loop is strange to me -

Comment: actually the problem is I have many such images(a database). with different kind of patterns/flowers and for all I want to find such repeating flowers or other patterns given one. If my algorithm is not even able to do it robustly for a single image how will i generalise it for so many images.

Comment: and the number of matches is also dependent upon how big the images are(resolution) -- if the resolution is higher then the number of false positives as well as the number of correct matches, both are more.

Comment: Generally, defining that 2 patterns "match" is kind of a shaky ground. Like, what do you actually mean saying 2 patterns match? They look similar to a human? Well, 2 different humans can look at the exactly same images and one would say they look alike, and the other one would say they don't. That's what's called an ill-posed problem. The provided code works reasonably well for a certain definition of "similar".

Comment: Your comment on resolution is also sensible. But it's like blaming the rain. It's not something you can completely avoid. You have more candidates, so you have more true positives as well as more false positives. If you'd have a "perfect" matching function - you'd have 0 false positives on any resolution. But once again, there's a problem to even define what a "perfect" match mean.